# loop increment with two output in the same loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

So, I need to get this output:

Loop 1 output (lower= 1, upper= 10, increment= 1)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

And

Loop 1 output (lower= 2, upper= 9, increment= 3)

2
5
8

but I'm only getting just the second one.
And this is my code:

```
public void loop1(int lower, int upper, int increment)
{   

    System.out.println("Loop 1 Output (lower= " + lower+ "," +
            " upper= " + upper+ "," + " increment= " + increment+ ")"); 
    for(int i = lower; i <= upper; i += increment)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }       
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
  }
```

could you please help me!

Update:
This is my code:

```
    public void loop1(int lb, int ub, int incr)
{   

    System.out.println("Loop 1 Output (lb = " + lb + "," +
            " ub = " + ub + "," + " incr = " + incr + ")"); 
    for(int i = lb; i <= ub; i += incr)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }       
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
  }


public void loop2(int lb, int ub, int incr)
{

    System.out.println("Loop 2 Output (lb = " + lb + "," +
            " ub = " + ub + "," + " incr = " + incr + ")");
    int n = lb;
    while(n <= ub)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
        n += incr;
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
}
```

AND THIS IS MY INPUT CLASS:

```
public class Driver

public static void main (String [] args)

    Loop lp = new Loop();

    lp.loop1(1, 10, 1); 
    lp.loop2(1, 10, 1);

    lp.loop1(2, 9, 3);
    lp.loop2(2, 9, 3);
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you just get second one? your method will works based on the values you will pass it into

Comment: I mean I just get this output: Loop 1 output (lower= 2, upper= 9, increment= 3)

2 5 8

Comment: what is your input ?

Comment: you need to call the method twice with different values for the method paramters inorder to have two different out put

Comment: May we see the whole program please, not just a snippet?

Comment: lp.loop1(1, 10, 1); 
lp.loop1(2, 9, 3);

Comment: please provide the whole code with the output you get

Comment: `System.out.println(i);` will never produce `2 5 8`

Comment: Are you missing some parts from the `Driver` class?  It would be easier for us to tell what's going on if you could post exactly what's in `Driver.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're calling your method only once, try calling:

```
loop1(1,10,1);
loop1(2,9,3);
```

I tested here and worked:

http://ideone.com/W0DM4H

Answer (score 0):

Call `loop1` with `1, 10, 1` and `2, 9, 3` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    loop1(1, 10, 1);
    loop1(2, 9, 3);
}
```

Then I believe you want a `static` method and you could use `printf()` to format your output like

```
public static void loop1(int lower, int upper, int increment) {
    System.out.printf("Loop 1 Output (lower=%d, upper=%d, increment=%d)%n",
            lower, upper, increment);
    System.out.print(lower);
    for (int i = lower + increment; i <= upper; i += increment) {
        System.out.printf(" %d", i);
    }
    System.out.printf("%n-----------------------------%n");
}
```

Anyway, the above works for me.